# Easier way to check if user has filled in a field?

Tags: php, html, css, variables, xhtml

I am trying to echo a message to the user if they did not fill in one or more areas of the form but it seems a little to intensive to have to put a lot of `else if` statements like below:

```
else if(empty($email) &&!empty($phone) &&!empty($username) &&!empty($password)) {
  echo '<span style="color:red">* You must enter a email</span>';   
} else if (!empty($email) &&empty($phone) &&!empty($username) &&!empty($password)) {
  echo '<span style="color:red">* You must enter a Phone Number</span>';
```

Is their a easier way to check multiple inputs eithout having to do a million `else if` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one cleaner way to do this.

```
$fields = array(
    array(
        'value' => $email,
        'label' => 'Email'
    ),
    array(
        'value' => $phone,
        'label' => 'phone number'
    ),
    array(
        'value' => $username,
        'label' => 'username'
    ),
    array(
        'value' => $password,
        'label' => 'password'
    ),
);

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (empty($field['value'])) {
        // do something with $field['label']
    }
}
```

Comment: So if one or more fields are empty it will display messages for those fields?

Comment: Yes. But if you want to only display 1 message you can add `break` inside the `if` statement.